# How to use forloop to instantiate/add a number of employees (all named Joe) to the list?

Tags: c#, loops, class, foreach

Note: This question was revised, so if you are reading the responses, please keep in mind that the question formerly asked for different first name data for each employee. Now they are all named Joe.

I've created a foreachloop that is supposed to go through several lists (one for each property) and instantiate an employee object with a first name of Joe, last name, and ID number.  All the employees must have the first name of "Joe", but different last names and ID numbers.  It would then add each new employee to a list called "Employees."  I have my lists of firstname, lastname and ID set up, but When I tried to print a list of employees to the console, it prints only one employee's info, 5 times. The loop seems to execute only the first item in every list. This is expected for first name (Joe is the only item in the list), but it should move on to the other last names and ID numbers each time.

Also: Many have said that foreach is not a good way to go about this; but my assignment specifically asks that I use a foreach loop to populate this list.  I'm not sure if having them all named Joe would make this more or less complicated, but that's what I need to do.

The Employee is its own class, and the list is in the program file. I've pasted both below.  The answer is probably obvious but I'd appreciate if you'd take a look at what may be going wrong.  I need the foreach loop to create one employee object for every item within the property lists and then print their info to the console. Thank you so much!  (And thank you to the responses from before the edit.  I'm now testing out your solutions and will update as I do so!)

#### Employee file:

```
namespace CSDrill_Loop
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

#### Program file:

```
namespace CSDrill_Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
            List<string> firstnames = new List<string>()
            {
                "Joe"
            };

            List<string> lastnames = new List<string>()
            {
                "Jackson", "Smith", "Miller", "Turner", "Johnson"
            };

            List<int> IDs = new List<int>()
            {
                34332, 54754, 43523, 87012, 43158
            };

            foreach (string firstname in firstnames)
            {
                foreach (string lastname in lastnames)
                {
                    foreach (int ID in IDs)
                    {

                        Employee Employeeobject = new Employee();
                        Employeeobject.firstname = firstname;
                        Employeeobject.lastname = lastname;
                        Employeeobject.ID = ID;
                        Employees.Add(Employeeobject);


                        foreach (Employee Employee in Employees)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Employeeobject.firstname + " "+Employeeobject.lastname+" "+Employeeobject.ID);
                            
                        }
                       Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move that last foreach loop outside of the other 3

Comment: all 3 lists will have same length always?

Comment: FrankerZ: I tried that but it threw a lot of errors for some reason. Good suggestion though

Comment: Just code: They may not always have 5 items each, but presumably every employee has a first and last name, and and ID, so they'd have the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be more like

```
**Employee file:**

namespace CSDrill_Loop
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Employee(string _firstName, string _lastName, int _ID)
        {
              firstname = _firstName;
              lastName = _lastName;
              ID = _ID;
        }
    }
}


**Program file:**

namespace CSDrill_Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
            List<string> firstnames = new List<string>()
            {
                "Bob", "Jeff", "Dale", "Kate", "Ann"
            };

            List<string> lastnames = new List<string>()
            {
                "Jackson", "Smith", "Miller", "Turner", "Johnson"
            };

            List<int> IDs = new List<int>()
            {
                34332, 54754, 43523, 87012, 43158
            };
            for(int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++)
            {
                Employees.Add(new Employee(firstNames[i], lastNames[i], IDs[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

if you only can use foreach then

```
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var firstName in firstNames)
            {
                Employees.Add(new Employee(firstName, lastNames[i], IDs[i]));
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you SILENT! This is great. For some reason, though, the assignment specifies that I should use "foreach" rather than just "for".  But I'm going to double check with them tomorrow to see if it's acceptable to set it up this way instead. Thanks again!

Comment: @FreddieMercury Updated it with foreach option. Mark as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem regarding printing:

Remove/Comment **Console.Readline()** and place it after the end of Outermost foreachloop i.e. firstnames.
You will get 5*5*5 = 125 Entries as per the nesting of your forloop.

Answer (score 1):

You may want a for loop instead of foreach loop. Be care of index of range exception.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < firstnames.Length; i++)
            {
                Employee Employeeobject = new Employee();
                Employeeobject.firstname = firstnames[i]; //get item by index
                Employeeobject.lastname = lastnames[i];
                Employeeobject.ID = IDs[i];
                Employees.Add(Employeeobject);

            }
```

Comment: Thank you Zen! This solution definitely makes sense.  For some reason, though, this assignment requires me to use "foreach."  I think it's to compare how much easier lambda functions are than foreach.  Later on, they ask me to create the same list with a lambda, but I just haven't gotten there yet.  I will be careful of the index of range exception, like you mentioned. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

This problem really doesn't make sense for a foreach loop given you have 3 separate lists where data is lined up like that. I'm guessing there was a misunderstanding with either the assignment or the input data structure. Either way if it's needed the only real way to do this would be to have a list of indexes to loop over and use that to access the different lists. Something like this should work for you. Also you really shouldn't have readline statements or any input in foreach loops.

```
List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
List<string> firstnames = new List<string>()
{
    "Bob", "Jeff", "Dale", "Kate", "Ann"
};

List<string> lastnames = new List<string>()
{
    "Jackson", "Smith", "Miller", "Turner", "Johnson"
};

List<int> IDs = new List<int>()
{
    34332, 54754, 43523, 87012, 43158
};

List<int> indexes = new List<int>()
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4
};

foreach (int index in indexes)
{
    Employee Employeeobject = new Employee();
    Employeeobject.firstname = firstnames[index];
    Employeeobject.lastname = lastnames[index];
    Employeeobject.ID = IDs[index];
    Employees.Add(Employeeobject);
}

foreach (Employee Employee in Employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Employee.firstname + " " + Employee.lastname + " " + Employee.ID);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: CodingKuma: Oh my gosh, you are right. I re-read the instructions and the first part says to create a list of employees but does not specify using "foreach," and Part Two says now use a foreach loop to make a list where all employees's first names are "Joe."  You're right, I'm so sorry for not catching it.  I'm going to edit this in my question. Thank you so much for your helpful solution and response!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see only 1 employee's info is because of this line:

> Console.ReadLine();

The application is not running until you press enter.

But the whole logic is also a bit wierd since the final output will be something like:

> A, A, B, A, B, C, A, B, C, D...(and 115 more employees!)

Instead of:

> A, B, C, D, E. (5 employees)

So according the info you provided, I don't think only one foreach loop will do the trick.